# Detox server doesn't get initialized on iOS and JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers

Tags: react-native, detox

I am trying to make e2e tests using Detox 
and i have faced problem as Detox server doesn't get initialized
and I get the following too :
`detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8)`

I hope that logs are not too long but here are the logs that I have in the artifact.

4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC 2020-02-19 15-16-51Z.startup

```
detox[48831] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:50871...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:50871
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] applesimutils --list --byType "iPhone X"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #1] applesimutils --list --byId 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC --maxResults 1
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #2] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #2] Uninstalling com.snowflake.hike...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] com.snowflake.hike uninstalled
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #3] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC "/Users/snowflake/DevSquads/snowflake/snowflake-react-native/ios/build/snowflake/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snowflake.app"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #3] Installing /Users/snowflake/DevSquads/snowflake/snowflake-react-native/ios/build/snowflake/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snowflake.app...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3] /Users/snowflake/DevSquads/snowflake/snowflake-react-native/ios/build/snowflake/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snowflake.app installed
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #4] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #4] Terminating com.snowflake.hike...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #4] com.snowflake.hike terminated
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #5] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #6] [pid=48872] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app\""
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #7] SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/snowflake/Library/Detox/ios/647caee43d053e07344915b0d5b71c85cb0b4733/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike --args -detoxServer "ws://localhost:50871" -detoxSessionId "c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8" -detoxPrintBusyIdleResources "YES"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #7] Launching com.snowflake.hike...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #8] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] com.snowflake.hike launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'process == snowflake'
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8)
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=testee, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=testee, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 48872]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #9] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #10] [pid=49499] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app\""
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #11] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC screenshot "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/ac4574f8-0716-40bd-9cdc-bc4dc6d0ffdb.detox.png"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #12] [pid=49503] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC recordVideo /private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/c0179e52-2fb0-49ab-90b8-30dc9dfa43db.detox.mp4
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timer: Tracking Timer <__NSCFTimer: 0x600003b0dd40>
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timer: Tracking Timer <__NSCFTimer: 0x600003b0dd40>
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timer: Tracking Timer <__NSCFTimer: 0x600003b0dd40>
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #13] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC screenshot "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/f98b8fab-208a-4d78-8153-d261dce44d90.detox.png"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 49503]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC recordVideo /private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/c0179e52-2fb0-49ab-90b8-30dc9dfa43db.detox.mp4
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] DEBUG: [SimulatorRecordVideoPlugin.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/c0179e52-2fb0-49ab-90b8-30dc9dfa43db.detox.mp4" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/test.mp4
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/ac4574f8-0716-40bd-9cdc-bc4dc6d0ffdb.detox.png" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/testStart.png
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/f98b8fab-208a-4d78-8153-d261dce44d90.detox.png" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/testDone.png
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 49499]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app"
detox[48831] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 1) invoke: {"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForText:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"Personalized to You"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForSufficientlyVisible","args":[]}}]}
  (id = -1000) reactNativeReload: {}

That might be the reason why the test "Example should show GET STARTED button" has timed out.

detox[48831] DEBUG: [SimulatorLogRecording.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/90c3bf5e-026e-42f8-a462-d8d32e57fd77.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/process.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [SimulatorLogRecording.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/864b0986-f94b-481a-8f81-6132f73f6558.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC 2020-02-19 15-16-51Z.startup.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/053ef6fa-1c4f-4f4a-bfc7-c7a0973c182a.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/detox_pid_48831.json.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/dc0d2b5c-4d65-471e-850e-f86af80747d8.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/detox_pid_48831.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=testee, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=tester not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8)
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
```

process.log

```
Filtering the log data using "processImagePath BEGINSWITH "/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app""
Timestamp               Ty Process[PID:TID]
2020-02-19 17:12:50.038 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.038 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.038 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.038 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.038 I  snowflake[48884:9d3f4] [com.wix.Detox:WXJSTimerObservationIdlingResource] Removing observed timer 17836
2020-02-19 17:12:50.039 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] WXRunLoopIdlingResource -> busy React Native thread is busy.
2020-02-19 17:12:50.039 I  snowflake[48884:9d3f4] [com.wix.Detox:WXJSTimerObservationIdlingResource] Observing timer: 17837 d: 0.001 r: 0
2020-02-19 17:12:50.039 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] WXRunLoopIdlingResource -> busy React Native thread is busy.
2020-02-19 17:12:50.039 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.039 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.039 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.054 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 I  snowflake[48884:9d3f4] [com.wix.Detox:WXJSTimerObservationIdlingResource] Removing observed timer 17837
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] WXRunLoopIdlingResource -> busy React Native thread is busy.
2020-02-19 17:12:50.055 I  snowflake[48884:9d3f4] [com.wix.Detox:WXJSTimerObservationIdlingResource] Observing timer: 17838 d: 0.001 r: 0
2020-02-19 17:12:50.056 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] WXRunLoopIdlingResource -> busy React Native thread is busy.
2020-02-19 17:12:50.056 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.056 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
2020-02-19 17:12:50.056 Db snowflake[48884:9d39b] [com.wix.Detox:EarlGreyStatistics] JavaScript Timers -> busy Javascript Timers
```

detox_pid_48831.log

```
detox[48831] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:50871...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:50871
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] applesimutils --list --byType "iPhone X"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #1] applesimutils --list --byId 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC --maxResults 1
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #2] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #2] Uninstalling com.snowflake.hike...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] com.snowflake.hike uninstalled
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #3] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC "/Users/snowflake/DevSquads/snowflake/snowflake-react-native/ios/build/snowflake/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snowflake.app"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #3] Installing /Users/snowflake/DevSquads/snowflake/snowflake-react-native/ios/build/snowflake/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snowflake.app...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3] /Users/snowflake/DevSquads/snowflake/snowflake-react-native/ios/build/snowflake/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snowflake.app installed
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #4] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #4] Terminating com.snowflake.hike...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #4] com.snowflake.hike terminated
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #5] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #6] [pid=48872] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app\""
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #7] SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/snowflake/Library/Detox/ios/647caee43d053e07344915b0d5b71c85cb0b4733/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike --args -detoxServer "ws://localhost:50871" -detoxSessionId "c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8" -detoxPrintBusyIdleResources "YES"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #7] Launching com.snowflake.hike...
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #8] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] com.snowflake.hike launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'process == snowflake'
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8)
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=testee, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=testee, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 48872]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #9] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC com.snowflake.hike
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #10] [pid=49499] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app\""
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #11] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC screenshot "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/ac4574f8-0716-40bd-9cdc-bc4dc6d0ffdb.detox.png"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #12] [pid=49503] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC recordVideo /private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/c0179e52-2fb0-49ab-90b8-30dc9dfa43db.detox.mp4
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #13] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC screenshot "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/f98b8fab-208a-4d78-8153-d261dce44d90.detox.png"
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 49503]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC recordVideo /private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/c0179e52-2fb0-49ab-90b8-30dc9dfa43db.detox.mp4
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] DEBUG: [SimulatorRecordVideoPlugin.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/c0179e52-2fb0-49ab-90b8-30dc9dfa43db.detox.mp4" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/test.mp4
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/ac4574f8-0716-40bd-9cdc-bc4dc6d0ffdb.detox.png" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/testStart.png
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/f98b8fab-208a-4d78-8153-d261dce44d90.detox.png" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/testDone.png
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[48831] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[48831] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 49499]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/snowflake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C2DE3FE-41FB-40C4-A0A6-7EC5819FD51E/snowflake.app"
detox[48831] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 1) invoke: {"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForText:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"Personalized to You"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForSufficientlyVisible","args":[]}}]}
  (id = -1000) reactNativeReload: {}

That might be the reason why the test "Example should show GET STARTED button" has timed out.

detox[48831] DEBUG: [SimulatorLogRecording.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/90c3bf5e-026e-42f8-a462-d8d32e57fd77.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/✗ Example should show GET STARTED button/process.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [SimulatorLogRecording.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/864b0986-f94b-481a-8f81-6132f73f6558.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/4D59B341-1D72-4537-A7A6-2685607D41FC 2020-02-19 15-16-51Z.startup.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/053ef6fa-1c4f-4f4a-bfc7-c7a0973c182a.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/detox_pid_48831.json.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [Artifact.js/MOVE_FILE] moving "/private/var/folders/35/t0nqj9vd2zd735xf5d05ybzr0000gn/T/dc0d2b5c-4d65-471e-850e-f86af80747d8.detox.log" to artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2020-02-19 15-07-46Z/detox_pid_48831.log
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=testee, sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=tester not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=c5f11579-4c6f-6735-87be-96d91fe111d8)
detox[48831] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the timer issue?